# Android run method each 5 minues

Tags: android

I have a Timer that makes some stuffs each 5 minutes. The question is where should i add this method? because if i add it in the "on create" method my Timer method executes only when my app is started. And i want to execute it each 5 minutes . Thanks in advice !

```
 private void timer() {
    final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // fetching file
        tcpClient.execute();
      }
    }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

EDIT : it looks like i need an AlarmManager as  Peter Birdsall and Aleksander Lidtke said
EDIT2: Now i have an AlarmManager set up , but still I can't run that method each 5 minutes , I'm new to Android , where should I call these things ? If i add it on the on create method it executes only 1 time, but i want it to execute forever , each 5 minutes.

THIS Saved ME https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/blob/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: "if i add it in the "on create" method my Timer method executes only when my app is started" and what exactly is your intent? Is it every 5 minutes while the app is running or every 5 minutes regardless?

Comment: Every 5 minutes regardless. Buy it would be ok for start every 5 minutes my app is running

Comment: If you want to do this regardless of whether app is running you need a service and a broadcast receiver for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` which will start your Service whenever the phone is running. If you want to do this in application try to play around with onResume and onStart.

Comment: Also, try `(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)` to set a task to be repeated recursively with its `.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_SENSORS, pendingIntent)` method (where `pendingIntent` would start the batch of code you want to execute).

Comment: All these in the On create method?

Comment: Try it `onResume` and see if it works and tell me if it doesn't. This method should be called when the Activity is first created and when you navigate back to it.

Comment: @Petrica see my answer that is exactly what u want to do

Comment: Doing a network request in the background every 5 minutes is going to drain the hell out of your user's batteries, please look into a push service like GCM

Comment: The final project will make network request every hour, but for testing i need minutes , i don t want to wait 1 hour for a test:)

Comment: The correct way to do this is using `AlarmManager` - the other answers are not optimal.

Comment: Well i made it with AlarmManager :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in the oncreate, it will not only execute once, I am absolutely positive.

```
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   tcpClient.execute();
               }
            }, 0, 300000);
```

Comment: What about screen rotation?

Comment: @Grzegorz The timer will reset.

Comment: @Petrica one second, I will give you another way to implement a timer that will work :)

Comment: @superuser I've tried the timer and it works properly, the problem is that i don't know where to add the method " timer()" in order to work properly , make tcpClien.execute() each 5 minutes.

Comment: @Petrica try the way I will soon post, you should put it in the oncreate

Comment: 09-05 13:23:27.134: E/AndroidRuntime(7320): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
09-05 13:23:27.134: E/AndroidRuntime(7320): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
09-05 13:23:27.134: E/AndroidRuntime(7320):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:538)
09-05 13:23:27.134: E/AndroidRuntime(7320):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
09-05 13:23:27.134: E/AndroidRuntime(7320):  at com.aaandroid.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:70)
09-05 13:23:27.134: E/AndroidRuntime(7320):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Comment: @Petrica I think it could be this: your tcpClient method is taking a long time to get done, and the timer tries to execute itself again while the tcpClient method from last time is still running. Try this change of time I put in the timer.

Comment: @Petrica I fixed it, I am so sorry, I made the mistake of putting only 300 milliseconds on the timer, I have fixed it in my answer, and it will now run every 5 minutes.

Comment: @superuser that time is in miliseconds ?:)

Comment: @superuser well  , that time is in milliseconds , i have increased that time in order to give my method time to make its work. But when its called second time , my app dies

Comment: @Petrica put in 300000 milliseconds. I have also edited my timer to make it work.

Comment: @superuser ok , just wait 5 minutes :)

Comment: @superuser It crashed

Comment: @Petrica try adding a timeout to your tcpClient.exeute Are you still using the other timer also? that could be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar type app.  I use a broadcastreceiver and a service that schedules it using the alarmmanager, that way you don't have much overhead, like running a timer, which has to stay active.

Here's my main activity.  I initiate the sequences with buttons.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

}



Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btn_splash) {
                initiateAlarm(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " alarm scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            } else if (v == btn_cancel)
                {

                initiateAlarm(false);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " alarm stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }

};



} 

public void initiateAlarm(Boolean bactive) {
      alarmUp = false;
        alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, 
               new Intent(this, YourService.class), 
               PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
                if (alarmUp)
                    {
                    Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
                    Toast.makeText(this, " before scheduling Alarm is already active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        YourReceiver.scheduleAlarms(this, prefDuration, bactive);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "alarms were just scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


         alarmUp = false;
         alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, 
                new Intent(this, YourService.class), 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
                if (alarmUp)
                    {
                    Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
                    Toast.makeText(this, " after scheduling Alarm is already active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
}

}
```

Here's the YourReceiver that schedules the service in the alarmmanager.

```
public class YourReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "YourReciever";



@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
  context = ctxt;

  scheduleAlarms(ctxt, (long) 3600001, true);  // 1 hour - not used

 }

 static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt, Long duration, Boolean bactive) {

  Log.e(TAG, " ... scheduleAlarms ");
  SharedPreferences preferences; 

  preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctxt); 
  prefDuration = preferences.getLong(PREF_DURATION, 3600000);  // 1 hour
  Log.e(TAG, " ... onReceive ... duration: " + duration);  

AlarmManager mgr=
    (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, 0);


mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                 SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + duration, duration, pi);
if (bactive == false) {
    mgr.cancel(pi);
}


 }

}
```

and finally here's the service class

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {




public YourService() {
    super("YourService");
    Log.e(TAG, " ... YourService");

}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


//
//  The action you want to perform.
//


}

}
```

Something like this needs be in the manifest.

```
 <service
        android:name="com.yourpackagename.YourService"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Action time tick broadcast. Here's an article that'll show you how. Very simple.

http://androidbridge.blogspot.ca/2011/08/how-to-use-actiontimetick-broadcast.html

That ticks every minute, so then in the reciever you just want to include something like

```
tick++
if(tick>=5)
{
    //Do what you want to do here

    tick=0;
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and just to be clear, you're going to have to declare tick as an int variable at the beginning of your activity so it doesn't go out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code it will help u call a function modify it according to u r requirement

```
private final long refreshDelay = 5 * 1000;
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.main);

            sendHttpRequestThread = new SendHttpRequestThread("","");
            sendHttpRequestThread.start();

        }

     class SendHttpRequestThread extends Thread {

            boolean sendHttpRequest;
            String userId;
            String pass;

            public SendHttpRequestThread(String str1, String str2) {
                this.userId = str1;
                this.pass = str2;
                sendHttpRequest = true;
            }

            public void stopSendingHttpRequest() {
                sendHttpRequest = false;
            }

            protected void onStop() {
                sendHttpRequestThread.stopSendingHttpRequest();
                super.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (sendHttpRequest) {
                    //Call U r function from here 

                    SystemClock.sleep(refreshDelay);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have used this call a method to send http request at every 5 sec see this is what u want hope this will help u